# How to use Redux Connect and customized HOC in same export

Tags: redux, react-hoc

i want to know how we can use Redux Connect and Customized HOC in same export.
for example we have component "TestComponent" and HOC "WithSampleHOC" and "Connect".

export default .....?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WithSampleHOC(Component));
```